# OpenGL ES 2.0 for iOS - multiple calls to glDrawElements causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, 3d

Several years ago, I wrote a small Cocoa/Obj-C game framework for OpenGL ES 1.1 and iPhone. This was back when iOS 3.x was popular. My OpenGL ES 1.1 / iOS 3.x implementation of this all worked fine. Time passed, and here we are now with iOS 5.1, OpenGL ES 2.0, ARC, blocks, and other things. I decided that it was high time to port the project over to more... modern standards.

**EDIT:** Solved one of the problems on my own - that of why it was crashing on the simulator. Sort of - I am now able to draw smaller models, but larger ones (like the test police car) still cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS - even if that is the only, single call to glDrawElements. I was also able to fix drawing-multiple-meshes on the Simulator - however, I don't know if this will function on-device until tomorrow morning. (my 5.0 test device is my friend's iPhone, don't). So I guess the main question is, why are larger models causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the simulator?

### Original post below

However, in moving it up to 5.0, I've run into some OpenGL ES 2.0 errors - two of them, specifically, although they may possibly be related. *The first of them is simple* - if I try to render my model on a device (iPhone 4S running 5.0.1), it displays, but if I try to display it on the simulator (iPhone Simulator running 5.0), it throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on glDrawElements. *The second, also simple.* I cannot draw multiple meshes. When I draw the model as one big group (one vertex array/index array combo) it draws fine - but when I draw the model as multiple parts (eg, multiple calls to drawElements) it fails, and displays a big black screen - the blackness is *not* from the model being drawn (I have verified this, outlined below).

To sum it up before the much-more-detailed part, attempting to render my model on the simulator crashes

**Caveat:** It all works fine for small meshes. I have no problem drawing my small, statically-declared cube over and over, even on the simulator. When I say statically-declared, I mean a hard-coded const array of structs that gets bound and loaded into the vertex buffer and a const array of GLushorts bound and loaded into the index array.

**Note:** when I say 'model' I mean an overall model, possibly made up of multiple vertex and index buffers. In code, this means that a *model simply holds an array of meshes or model-groups*. A mesh or model-group is a sub-unit of a model, eg one contiguous piece of the model, has one vertex array and one index array, and stores the lengths of both as well. In the case of the model I've been using, the body of the car is one mesh, the windows another, the lights a third. All together, they make up the model.

The model I am using is a police car, has several thousand vertices and faces, and is split into multiple parts (body, lights, windows, etc) - the body is about 3000 faces, the windows about 100, the lights a bit less.

Here are some things to know:

1. My model is loading properly. I have verified this in two ways -
   printing out the model vertices and manually inspecting them, and
   displaying each model-group individually as outlined in 2). I'd post images, but 'reputation limit' and this being my first question, I can't. I have also re-built the model loader twice from scratch with no change, so I know the vertex and index buffers are in the correct order/format.
2. When I load the model as a single model-group (ie, one vertex
   buffer/index buffer) it displays the whole model correctly. When I
   load the model as multiple model-groups, and display any given
   model-group individually, it displays correctly. When I try to draw
   multiple model-groups (multiple calls to glDrawElements) the big
   black screen happens.
3. The black screen is not because of the model being drawn. *I
   verified this by changing my fragment shader to draw every pixel
   **red** no matter what.* I always clear the color buffer to a medium-gray (I clear the depth buffer as well, obviously), but attempting to draw multiple meshes/model-groups results in a black screen. We know it is not the model simply obscuring the view because it is colored black instead of red. This occurs on the device, I do not know what would happen on the simulator as I cannot get it to draw.
4. My model will not draw in the simulator. It will not draw as either a single mesh/model-group, nor multiple mesh/model-groups. The application loads properly, but
   attempting to draw a mesh/model-group results in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the
   glDrawElements. The relevant parts of the backtrace are:

   ```
    thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x10b002b5, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x94fd020)
       frame #0: 0x10b002b5
       frame #1: 0x09744392 GLEngine`gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore + 883
       frame #2: 0x09742a9b GLEngine`glDrawElements_ES2Exec + 505
       frame #3: 0x00f43c3c OpenGLES`glDrawElements + 64
       frame #4: 0x0001cb11 MochaARC`-[Mesh draw] + 177 at Mesh.m:81
   ```

   **EDIT:** It consistently is able to draw smaller dynamically-created models (~100 faces) but the 3000 of the whole model
5. I was able to get it to render a much-smaller, less-complicated, but still dynamically loaded, model consisting of 192 faces / 576 vertices. I was able to display it both as a single vertex and index buffer, as well as split up into parts and rendered as multiple smaller vertex and index buffers. Attempting to draw the single-mesh model in the simulator resulted in the EXC_BAD_ACCESS still being thrown, but only on the first frame. If I force it to continue, it displays a very screwed up model, and then every frame after that, it displayed 100% fine exactly as it ought to have.
6. My shaders are not in error. They compile and display correctly when I use a small, statically declared vertex buffer. However, for completeness I will post them at the bottom.

---

My code is as follows:

**Render loop:**

```c
glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //muShader is a subclass of a shader-handler I've written that tracks the active shader
    //and handles attributes/uniforms
    //[muShader use] just does glUseProgram(muShader.program); then
    //disables the previous shader's attributes (if needed) and then
    //activates its own attributes - in this case:
    //it does:
    //    glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.position);
    //    glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.uv);
    //where position and uv are handles to the position and texture coordinate attributes
[self.muShader use];

GLKMatrix4 model = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_rotation), 0, 1, 0);
GLKMatrix4 world = GLKMatrix4Identity;
GLKMatrix4 mvp = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_camera.projection, _camera.view);
mvp = GLKMatrix4Multiply(mvp,world);
mvp = GLKMatrix4Multiply(mvp, model);

    //muShader.modelViewProjection is a handle to the shader's model-view-projection matrix uniform
glUniformMatrix4fv(self.muShader.modelViewProjection,1,0,mvp.m);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.policeTextureID);
    //ditto on muShader.texture
glUniform1i(self.muShader.texture, 0);

for(int i=0; i < self.policeModel.count; i++)
{
        //I'll expand muShader readyForFormat after this
    [self.muShader readyForFormat:ModelVertexFormat];
        //I'll expand mesh draw after this
    [[self.policeModel meshAtIndex:i] draw];
}
```

---

**muShader stuff**

muShader binding attributes and uniforms

I won't post the whole muShader's class, it is unnecessary, suffice to say that it works or else it'd not display anything at all, ever.

```c
//here is where we bind the attribute locations when the shader is created
-(void)bindAttributeLocations
{
    _position = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "position");
    _uv = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "uv");
}
//ditto for uniforms
-(void)bindUniformLocations
{
    _modelViewProjection = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "modelViewProjection");
    _texture = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "texture");
}
```

muShader readyForFormat

```c
-(void)readyForFormat:(VertexFormat)vertexFormat
{
    switch (vertexFormat)
    {
        //... extra vertex formats removed for brevity
        case ModelVertexFormat:

            //ModelVertex is a struct, with the following definition:
            //typedef struct{
            //    GLKVector4 position;
            //    GLKVector4 uv;
            //    GLKVector4 normal;
            //}ModelVertex;

            glVertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ModelVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
            glVertexAttribPointer(_uv, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ModelVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(16));
            break;
        //... extra vertex formats removed for brevity
    }
}
```

---

**Mesh stuff**

setting up the vertex/index buffers

```c
//this is how I set/create the vertex buffer for a mesh/model-group
//vertices is a c-array of ModelVertex structs
//    created with malloc(count * sizeof(ModelVertex))
//    and freed using free(vertices) - after setVertices is called, of course
-(void)setVertices:(ModelVertex *)vertices count:(GLushort)count
{
    //frees previous data if necessary
    [self freeVertices];
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ModelVertex) * count, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    _vertexCount = count;

}
//this is how I set/create the index buffer for a mesh/model-group
//indices is a c-array of GLushort,
//    created with malloc(count * sizeof(GLushort);
//    and freed using free(vertices) - after setVertices is called, of course
-(void)setIndices:(GLushort *)indices count:(GLushort)count
{
    [self freeIndices];
    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * count, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    _indexCount = count;
}
```

mesh draw

```c
//vertexBuffer and indexBuffer are handles to a vertex/index buffer
//I have verified that they are loaded properly
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

---

**Shader stuff**

Vertex Shader

```
attribute highp vec4 position;
attribute lowp vec3 uv;

varying lowp vec3 fragmentUV;

uniform highp mat4 modelViewProjection;
uniform lowp sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    fragmentUV = uv;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjection * position;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
varying lowp vec3 fragmentUV;

uniform highp mat4 modelViewProjection;
uniform lowp sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture,fragmentUV.xy);
    //used below instead to test the aforementioned black screen by setting
    //every pixel of the model being drawn to red
    //the screen stayed black, so the model wasn't covering the whole screen or anything
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answered it myself, when using multiple buffer objects, glEnableVertexAttribArray has to be called for every time you bind the vertex/index buffer object, rather than simply once per frame (per shader). This was the cause of all of the problems, including the simulator crashing.

Closed.